# No notification for custodian badge

Tags: bug, status-bydesign, badges, notifications

I've just discovered [review](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/review/) and got [two Custodian badges](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/badges/120/custodian?userid=51770) for it, sweet! But I never got a notification for them, as I did for every other badge, and only discovered them when I noticed my bronze badge count incrementing.

[image]

This was also [reported yesterday on Meta StackOverflow](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/147918/didnt-get-notifications-for-custodian-badge), and it seems a bit random as [some people did get notifications](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/147922/small-typo-in-the-notification-for-new-community-review-badges).

Comment: Double check the notification tab in the top left widget. Are you sure they're not listed?

Comment: @jmort253 Updated the question with a screenshot of the widget.

Comment: I'd say that looks like a possible bug then. +1

Comment: @jmort253 Just found out someone else [reported this on Meta StackOverflow](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/147918/didnt-get-notifications-for-custodian-badge), should I delete it from here?

Comment: I don't think you need to, but it wouldn't hurt to post a link to this bug on the MSO post as a comment, as the extra info may be helpful. If this isn't needed, the community or mods will close it.

Comment: @jmort253 Done, thanks.

Answer (score 5):

Most of the bronze badges don't notify users who are considered "veterans" of the network, which is (loosely) defined as having accounts on multiple non-meta sites.

The rationale is that getting a notification everytime you join a new site and, say, downvote gets a tad annoying after a while.

Custodian, being one of the "you did one thing"-bronze badges is one of those who's notifications are suppressed.

Comment: Hm? Seems to be working backwards then, I got notifications for Custodian (38K net rep and a diamond), the OP didn't (690 net rep).

Comment: @YannisRizos _working backwards_ yeah it's like someone mistakenly put `true` instead of `false` in a piece of code intended to decide whether to send notification or not :)

Comment: @Kevin just got yet another notification for Custodian on Programmers, this doesn't seem to be working properly. Don't really consider myself a veteran, but getting notifications on a site I have a diamond on when the OP, a very new user, doesn't is a bit silly.

Comment: @Yannis for some reason your user profile did not have the IsVeteran bit set.  I have set this manually for you on programmers.se and will look into ways this could possibly happen for other users.

Comment: @GeoffDalgas Just got custodian and critic on Workplace, no notification for either. Can I assume I'm a veteran too? :-P Don't care about the notifications, but this isn't really working as expected. Low priority obviously, but not [status-completed].

Answer (score 3):

Not really an answer, just confirmation that custodian badges generate notifications:

[image]

Smells like a bug.

**Update**

Although I just got [custodian on Code Review](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/badges/86/custodian?userid=4673), there was no notification.

Comment: I got notifications for mine.

Comment: No notifications for mine... across a number of sub-sites...

Comment: If this works for me and not anyone else, it would be the silliest mod only feature ever ;P

Comment: it's not mod-only feature: custodian notifications work for me :)

Comment: It appears that it might be related to level of reputation.

Answer (score 0):

As a further issue relating to this badge, its inclusion in the Badge Count depends on which list (and which site) you are reviewing

It also is sometimes counted once (irrespective of the number you hold) or multiply... or not at all!

Comment: It would be preferable to ask a Meta question about further issues you are experiencing with the badge, please don't post answers that don't answer the question, even partially.